# how to validate Radio button in GWT

Tags: gwt

I have two radio buttons and text field and i want to have validator that one radio checked, the text field must not be null.

**Here is the code:**

```
radio1 = new Radio();
radio1.setBoxLabel("yes");
radio1.setId("active");
radio1.setValue(false);

radio2 = new Radio();
radio2.setBoxLabel("no");
radio2.setId("deactive");
radio2.setValue(true);

final RadioGroup defaultRadioGroup = new RadioGroup();
defaultRadioGroup.setFieldLabel("activeا");
defaultRadioGroup.add(radio1);
defaultRadioGroup.add(radio2);
simpleForm.add(defaultRadioGroup, formData); 


labelField = new TextField<String>(); 
labelField.setEmptyText("please insert value");
labelField.setReadOnly(true);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this carefully: [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a new Validator for the textbox and then call textbox.validate()

Other option is to check if your textbox class supports any utility method like "allowEmpty(boolean)"